# How do I generate a random number between 1 and 0 in SAS?

Tags: random, sas

A simple enough question. I'm trying to implement a method for partial imputation in order to compensate for missing values. What I need to do is to find the distribution of answer for a certain subgroup (say that 90 percent of the swiss like cheese and 10 percent don't), generate a random value for each observation. If that random value is <=0.9 the person who hasn't answered likes cheese in the previous example, and otherwise he or she does not.

But how exactly do I code this?

I gather I'm probably supposed to use the RAND function, but with what arguments? Also, do I need to set a random seed somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call the Rand Function without arguments (default is uniform with mu=0 and sigma = 1). If you want reproducible result, you can set the Call Streaminit() with an integer argument in the data step.

```
data _null_;
   call streaminit(123);
   rand = rand('uniform');
   put rand=;
run;
```